# Login Attack clues

Tags: javascript, passwords

I want to send an alert email to a user if someone is trying to hack there account

> "Just now someone tried to login to your account with eMail: **"+em+"** and Password: **"+pw+"**, if this wasn't you it might be a good time to increase your password security or change the email associated with your account."

Additional details may include more identifiable information:

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",function(_){_.ip});

navigator.platform

navigator.language
```

Are there any other info/clues I can send?

The idea is that

- the user will feel safer that we can see the attacker
- they will be able to identify them selves over someone else
- they might know who it is in real life

Comment: I would not include the password in the email as any small typos in the password will mean that the password (or an almost correct version of it) will be sent in the clear and will end up in the user's mailbox (not a good place for storing passwords). Also, if two people have similar email addresses, any typos in the email address will give their password to another user.

Comment: What about, telling the user how close to cracking they were 1-10 ?

Comment: You should be storing the passwords salted and hashed, so you should have no idea how close to the real password they were.